# php mysqli error trigger fatal error on php level instead of mysqli_error from query result since update php 8

Tags: php, mysqli

Since I update php from 7 to 8, my mysqli exceptions trigger fatal error on php level, and then trigger a GUI fatal error message.

Before, when on php 7, the script continue and i can process the mysqli_error and show the message with correct formating (gui friendly).

I think i have to do some php.ini conf but i didn't succeed to have the expect result as before.
I trye play with error_reporting:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING
```

with no success.

Anyone know how to prevent mysql query/syntax error to trigger a php error but still keep the mysqli_error available ?

Thank you

Comment: https://php.watch/versions/8.1/mysqli-error-mode

Comment: Why would you want to prevent mysqli from throwing exceptions? Why not just fix the underlying error?

Comment: Dharman, I don't want to ignore issues. I want to have control on how I can display them.